# Java: How to create a public class that can be subclassed within package, while preventing outsiders from inheriting?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, access-modifiers

Suppose I am writing a package. I have the following inheritance hierarchy, all within my package:

```
public class Container {
    public void size() {
        System.out.println(10);
    }
}

public final class Bucket extends Container {}

public final class Bag extends Container {}

public class Item {
    Container container; // is aware of what container it's in. Will be initialized on construction.
    public Container getContainer() {
        return container;
    } 
}
```

I want to prevent others from subclassing `Container`. But I can't make it `final` because `Bucket` and `Bag` are subclasses. And I have to make it `public` or else outsiders cannot call `getContainer()`. Is there a way to do this in Java? Otherwise, what do people do in this type of situation?

Comment: So to clarify what you may be asking.... you want a class called `Container` that has two, and ONLY two, subclasses called `Bucket` and `Bag`, right?

Comment: Yes. I just realized that the closest thing I can think of to preventing it from being subclassed outside is to make `Container`'s constructors package-private. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Sounds quite reasonable indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent a class from being subclassed by classes in other packages, make all the constructors **package-private**.

If the class doesn't have any constructors, it has the [implicit default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), which is public, so you need to explicitly create a package-private no-arg constructor.

```
package foo;
public class Container {
  Container () {/*package-private*/}
  public void size() { System.out.println(10); }
}
```

---

```
package foo;
public final class Bucket extends Container {}
```

---

```
package bar;
public final class Oops extends Container {}
```

*Compile Error:* Implicit super constructor Container() is not visible for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

---

```
public final class Oops extends Container {
  public Oops() {}
}
```

*Compile Error:* Implicit super constructor Container() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Of course, there are no other constructors, so it cannot be done.